# from nltk import WhitespaceTokenizer gives ImportError: No module named nltk

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to tokenize words in a string using Python nltk and I need to import the following modules:

```
from nltk import WhitespaceTokenizer
from nltk import WordPunctTokenizer
```

But it fails to import these modules:

```
>>ImportError: No module named nltk
```

I can `import nltk` and also `dir(nltk)` shows me the two modules are present: WhitespaceTokenizer, WordPunctTokenizer

Has anyone faced this problem? I am using Python 2.6.1

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed?

Comment: yes.. there are 2 versions of Python 2.6.1 on the box where I am running the code. Is that the reason? What is confusing is, if I can import nltk why I am not able to import these modules, when I see them listed in dir(nltk)

Comment: It could be... try printing sys.version after you successfully run dir(ntlk) and then ensure the python file you are writing is using the same version.

Answer (score 0):

*Install nltk:*

```
pip install nltk
```

**Or you can download a pre-compiled version from here:** http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#nltk

*Install using .whl file*

```
pip install nltk-3.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

**Your import statement should be:**

```
from nltk.tokenize import WhitespaceTokenizer, WordPunctTokenizer
```

Answer (score -1):

Does the following code work for you?

```
import nltk
WhitespaceTokenizer = nltk.WhitespaceTokenizer
WordPunctTokenizer = nltk.WordPunctTokenizer
```

Which version of `nltk` are you using? Try to update to the latest version. Your code works on my configuration (Python 2.7 with nltk 2.0.1rc4).